# one-liner bash script to detect missing PATHs

Tags: bash

I was finding my bash terminal a little slow, and found a suggestion saying to check your $PATH to see whether there were incorrect entries. There was and I fixed it up. However, I wanted to write a quick one-liner to make it easy for people to check their $PATH.

I came up with this (on OSx)

`echo $PATH | tr : "\n" | xargs -I {} bash -c ' if [ ! -e "{}" ] ; then echo {}; fi; '`

It *basically* works, except that for one particular directory it is saying that it doesn't exist, when it does.

The directory in question as far as I can see is a real directory, it's not a symlink, I can `cd` into it and run `ls` ...

Running the above command it gives me one directory `"/Users/patrickdavey/bin"`, but then I can run stat:

```
stat /Users/patrickdavey/bin
16777220 7650031 drwxr-xr-x 3 patrickdavey staff 0 102 "Aug 23 22:42:29 2016" "May 24 03:03:41 2016" "May 24 03:03:41 2016" "May 24 03:03:32 2016" 4096 0 0 /Users/patrickdavey/bin
```

so, it definitely exists.

If anyone can point out what might be wrong in my above script I'd really appreciate it! :)

for @john1024 -

```
$ cd ~/
$ pwd
/Users/patrickdavey
$ (IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 0 ! -type d)
find: ~/bin: No such file or directory
$ stat ~/bin
16777220 7650031 drwxr-xr-x 4 patrickdavey staff 0 136 "Aug 24 20:39:24 2016" "Aug 24 16:34:09 2016" "Aug 24 16:34:09 2016" "May 24 02:03:32 2016" 4096 0 0 /Users/patrickdavey/bin
```

Comment: I think that this does what you want but is much simpler: `(IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 0 ! -type d)`.  As for why your command fails on one and only one directory, it would help if your provided more information such as your full path and the _exact_ and _complete_ output.

Comment: no need for find - IFS=:; ls -d $PATH >/dev/null - stick a sed at the end if you want just the missing paths

Comment: @John1024 I added a section where I cd into ~/ and then run the command you gave. Please let me know what other output you'd like. It still says the directory doesn't exist (when it clearly does)

Comment: @patrick-davey Thanks.  I think that that is enough to figure it out.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that this generates no errors:

```
$ (PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:~/bin; IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 0 ! -type d)
```

By contrast, this generates an error message similar to the one that you see:

```
$ (PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:~/bin"; IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 0 ! -type d)
find: ‘~/bin’: No such file or directory
```

The problem is that, in this version, the `~` is in quotes.  `~/` only means the home directory if it is *unquoted*.

Note that you can still use quotes to define your PATH.  They just cannot include the `~/`.  For example, the following works with no error:

```
$ (PATH="/bin:/usr/bin":~/"bin"; IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 0 ! -type d)
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> Each  variable  assignment  is checked for **unquoted tilde-prefixes
>   immediately following a `:` or the first `=`.**  In these cases, tilde
>   expansion is also performed.  Consequently, one may use filenames with
>   tildes in assignments to PATH, MAILPATH, and CDPATH, and the shell
>   assigns the expanded value. [Emphasis added.]

Also from `man bash`:

> **Tilde Expansion**
>
> **If  a word begins with an unquoted tilde character** (`~'), all of the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or all
>   characters, if there is no  unquoted slash) are considered a
>   tilde-prefix.  If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are
>   quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix  following the tilde are
>   treated as a possible login name.  If this login name is the null
>   string, the tilde is replaced with the value of the shell parameter
>   HOME.  If HOME is unset, the home directory of the user executing the
>   shell is substituted instead.  Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced
>   with the home directory associated with the specified login name. [Emphasis added]

Comment: Brilliant! thanks @John2014 - and nice to come across `IFS` too - I'll have to have a play with that one.